# Literal array in C

Tags: c

I may be wrong in my definition of what a literal array is. I am refering to the following as one:

```
{0x00, 0x01, 0x03}
```

I have a function that accepts an array as shown below:

```
void mote(char arry[]){}
```

When I am calling this function I would like to be able to do the following:

```
mote({0x00, 0x01, 0x03})
```

However my compiler(C30) complains with the following error:

```
error: syntax error before '{' token
```

I also tried the above with these brackets -> [  ] but i still get the same error.

**My questions**

1) Is it possible to pass a literal array into a function?

2) If yes, how?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Yes that is similar question thank you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This syntax is called *array initializer*. Therefore, it can be used only when you define your array.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.7.9 Initialization
>
> ```
> initializer:
>     assignment-expression
>     { initializer-list }
>     { initializer-list , }
> ```

However, in C99, it is possible to do it  with *compound literals*:

```
mote((char[]){0x00, 0x01, 0x03});
```

Comment: Note: If the function can be made to take `const char arry[]` (likely, since the mere fact of passing a compound literal implies the caller doesn't need the result, so unless the function is using it as scratch space, it should be possible to make it `const`), passing `(const char[]){0x00, 0x01, 0x03}` allows the compiler to use static storage (baked into binary's constants section) shared with string literals; without the `const` (and on compilers that don't merge w/string literals), outside global scope, the literal would be reconstructed on each use (it only has automatic storage duration).

Answer (score 9):

if C99 is not supported, try this one:

```
char cp[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
mote (cp);
```